# Loading Blaze-persistence entity view by JPA specification

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, blaze-persistence

I have a "vanilla" JPA specification prepared for certain entity. I also have Blase-persistence entity view interface prepared for the same entity. How can I load that entity view using prepared JPA specification?

Edit:
Currently, I'm using this specification like so:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<EntityClass> query = cb.createQuery(EntityClass.class);
Root<EntityClass> root = query.from(EntityClass.class);
query.where(specification.toPredicate(root, query, cb));
EntityGraph graph = entityManager.getEntityGraph(entityGraphName);
TypedQuery<EntityClass> = entityManager.createQuery(query)
.setHint("javax.persistence.loadgraph", graph);
List<EntityClass> result = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

After that, I'm converting list of entities into list of projections.
Right now, I'm trying to replace both entity graphs and projections with entity views in similar scenario, with class for entity view coming as parameter.

Comment: Do you mean a Spring Data JPA specification?

Comment: I mean, implementation of an interface org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification. Was using it even outside Spring Data repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the `CriteriaQuery`, or actually `BlazeCriteriaQuery`, to a Blaze-Persistence `CriteriaBuilder` as outlined in the [quickstart](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#jpa-criteria-api-quick-start) which would look roughly like this:

```
// This is a subclass of the JPA CriteriaBuilder interface
BlazeCriteriaBuilder cb = BlazeCriteria.get(criteriaBuilderFactory);
// A subclass of the JPA CriteriaQuery interface
BlazeCriteriaQuery<EntityClass> query = cb.createQuery(EntityClass.class);
Root<EntityClass> root = query.from(EntityClass.class);
query.where(specification.toPredicate(root, query, cb));
// Finally, transform the BlazeCriteriaQuery to the Blaze-Persistence Core CriteriaBuilder
CriteriaBuilder<EntityClass> builder = query.createCriteriaBuilder(entityManager);
```

At this point, you can apply a `EntityViewSetting` onto that query and retrieve the results as outlined in the [entity-view quickstart](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage):

```
CriteriaBuilder<MyEntityView> viewBuilder = evm.applySetting(EntityViewSetting.create(MyEntityView.class), builder );
List<MyEntityView> myViews = viewBuilder .getResultList();
```

Comment: That almost works, but I'm getting an error during call to this method:
InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unsupported cast type: java.time.LocalDate. Should I include some compatibility maven dependencies to make java.time classes supported?

Comment: Can you share the relevant code part that throws this exception? Maybe the cast is not necessary?

Comment: Relevant part is part of specification. It's case clause (basically, take one date if not null, if it is - take another), which later used in comparison (so it has to be date, or exception is thrown).
Found workaround by casting to java.SQL.Date instead (and casting values used for comparison as well), but there is another problem.
When resulting sql code is generated just by JPA+Hibernate, this cast does not appear there, case clause works as is. But with blaze-persistence, case clause is casted to date (cast - case expression - as date) in generated sql code, and that slows execution down

Comment: Update: unnecessary cast is consequences of using java.sql.Date class in general, in both JPA + Hibernate and blaze-persistence approaches. So, I need conversion to LocalDate for case expression in specification.

Comment: I can try to implement a fix for this, but for now you might have to use `cb.function("treat_localdate", LocalDate.class, arg)` as workaround which will omit the cast in SQL.